# Vagrant provision getting 404

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I'm stucked provisioning in vagrant, whenever run vagrant provision it shows me error like:

http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/vim-enhanced-7.2.411-1.8.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.

Error Downloading Packages:
  libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64: failure: Packages/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64: failure: Packages/libjpeg-turbo-devel-1.2.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Comment: how do you do provisioning (shell, chef, puppet) ? do you get something if you run `yum list libjpeg-turbo-devel` in the VM, what are the repos that are configured

Comment: Maybe this Ansible  "Ansible failed to complete successfully." i'm new to vagrant

Comment: After running yum list libjpeg-turbo-develCould not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64 error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrors.fedoraproject.org'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the repo you're using at not good enough.

Just to be sure, add the following in your Vagrantfile before your unusable provisioning:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo wget https://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol6.repo -P /etc/yum.repos.d --no-check-certificate"
```

After you have this, you should at least be able to run `yum list libjpeg-turbo-devel` and find the package

```
[vagrant@home]$ yum list libjpeg-turbo-devel
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, downloadonly, remove-with-leaves, security
Available Packages
libjpeg-turbo-devel.i686                                                                                                                 1.2.1-3.el6_5                                                                                                                ol6_latest
libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64                                                                                                               1.2.1-3.el6_5                                                                                                                ol6_latest
```